# LUT optimization - Converting irregularly spaced grids to regularly spaced grids

Tags: matlab, optimization, lookup-tables, nonlinear-optimization

[This optimization technique](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35194-table-breakpoint-optimization) works great to optimize 3D Look Up Tables (LUTs) and appropriately minimize errors due to interpolation.

Using this optimization tool, the nodes become unevenly spaced in order to best fit the input data, however, for my application, I need to have evenly spaced nodes within my lookup table. This is due to constraints of the LUT implementation where the nodes are specified as a min and max and assumed to be evenly spaced between those values. [This is an examples](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/speedgrade/cc/pdfs/cube-lut-specification-1.0.pdf) of such an implementation although it’s common for many lut formats to do the same thing.

I want to be able to utilize the optimization, but also create a uniformly spaced table. Is there a way to convert the optimized table to table with evenly spaced nodes without losing the optimization perhaps using a preceding 1D shaper LUT?  Maybe by effectively shaping the data going into the uniformly spaced table 3D such that the results would match those of the optimized 3D alone.

Comment: Did you looked at Tucker McClure (9 Aug) comments? There isn't much to optimise (3 variables at max) when you need an equally spaced grid. Converting from irregularly to a regularly spaced grid is impossible without exploding the number of gridpoints.

Comment: I don't think that comment addresses the problem.  He's effectively suggesting trying different numbers of nodes.

Comment: And why isn't that a good approach? As an alternative, you can use builtin optimisation function in MATLAB. Converting an irregular grid to a regular one is useless (and computation time intensive overall).

Comment: It's a brute force approach that makes the LUT files extremely large. Hoping to do something a little smarter and put the nodes where they matter most.

Comment: It's worth noting that it's common to "move nodes" to a more useful position with a shaper LUT when applying 3D luts to images.  Typically this is done by applying a linear to log shaper prior to a regularly spaced 3D lut.  The nodes are then effectively linearly spaced in log space putting more nodes in the darker parts of the image where they are considered more useful.  I'm trying to take this concept further by optimizing the node spacing with a shaper based on the underlying function rather than simply assuming a log spacing is optimal.